# Why does File.createTempFile return a symlink on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos

I just found out that on Mac OS X the method File.createTempFile returns a symlink to a file, not an actual file. Does anyone know the reason for this behavior? (Context: This causes my file walker to fail because it ignores all symlinks.)

**Edit**: I'm calling File.createTempFile(String,String,File), where the third argument is a File created from System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir").

Comment: Hm, didn't realize that. Out of curiosity, where is the actual file located that it points to?

Comment: Which version of `File.createTempFile` are you using? (The method is overloaded.)

Comment: normalocity & aioobe: Can't answer those questions because I don't have access to a Mac right now :-(

Comment: Well, how many arguments do you pass to the `createTemFile` method?!

Comment: @aioobe: I'm calling File.createTempFile(String,String,File). The third argument is sometimes null.

Comment: Then my answer applies to your situation.

Comment: What I'm actually calling is File.createTempFile(String,String,File), where the last argument is a file created from System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir").

Answer (score 2):

> ***I'm calling File.createTempFile(String,String,File)***

Presumably because it want the file to occupy space in `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`, but, due to the [contract of the method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29), it needs to put the file in the provided (third argument) directory.

It is important for security reasons to put the file in a designated "temporary" directory such as `/tmp`. Many systems have a separate partition for this directory, in order to prevent malicious input to fill up the disk.

Comment: I haven't marked this as 'accepted' because I don't think it's the correct answer: As I said in the comments above, the File argument is just the default temporary directory, so the problem can't be related to custom temporary directories. Anyways, sorry about not mentioning this crucial detail earlier, I needed some time to dig through the codebase...